# Pass params to the loadData() to override the emptyText prop in viewCconfig method-EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to load the store with no records unless I check for certain condition. However I want to pass params to my loadData() in such a way that I can override the emptyText property with some other text.

```
    this.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
            viewConfig:{
              emptyText: "No Records"
             },
            fields: [],
      });

    this.on('afterrender', function(){
        new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function() {
          this.getStore().loadData([]); //loading empty data
        }, this).delay(300);
    }, this);
```

So when I load the store I want to replace the `emptyText: "Select actions`" and once action selected it will display records or no records depending on the data.

If I insert the "Selection actions' text above in the viewConfig, it works ok on page load, but when no records found, it still displays the "Select actions".Is there any way I pass params to the loadData() function to override the text?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @Saloo's example works, let me show you what object orientation can do for you.

If you don't want to copy the code over and over, behind every `loadData`, you can, in your store definition, override the existing loadData function to add another parameter, for example:

```
loadData:function(data, append, emptyText) {
    if(emptyText) {
        grid.emptyText = '<b> ' + emptyText + ' </b>';
        grid.getView().refresh();
    }
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

and there you go.

Comment: what is callParent(arguments)?

Comment: @user1234 [It calls the function you have "replaced" (the original loadData function), as per the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Base-method-callParent).

Answer (score 1):

loadData() method doesn't take any parameter.

```
loadData( data, [append] )
```

You have to handle any other event like select of combo and then change the viewConfig emptyText manually based on your condition and then refresh the view.

I have done this on grid component like this:

```
if (Ext.isEmpty(records)) {
        grid.emptyText = '<b> No Document Found </b>';
        grid.getView().refresh();
   }
```